# Why does slice assignment get rid of the outer tuple in Python

Tags: python

The output I expected:

```
>>> [1, ("Hello", (2, 3)), 4]
```

...with this  code:

```
rl = [1, 4]
test_sl = ("Hello", (2, 3))
rl[1:1] = test_sl
print(rl)
```

instead brought me:

```
>>> [1, "Hello", (2, 3), 4] # No tuple around "Hello", (2, 3)
```

Why?

Comment: you can useing `r1[1] = test_s1` to get you want

Comment: I appreciate the input. This replaces the 2 with the tuple. I'm looking to insert *between* [1, *here*, 2] with the tuple in tact. (Will modify for clarity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of how slice assignment works in python. You can only assign an iterable to a slice, and python will assign all the items from iterating over the iterable to the slice. For example:

```
>>> def ten():
...   for n in range(10):
...     yield(n+1)
... 
>>> a = ['hello']
# directly assigning an iterable - function that yields things
>>> a[1:1] = ten()
>>> a
['hello', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# a string can be an iterable - iterates over its characters
>>> a[2:2]  = 'hello'
>>> a
['hello', 1, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# can't assign something that isn't iterable!
>>> a[1:1] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only assign an iterable
# as a tuple is iterable, only the contents will be assigned to the list
>>> a[1:1] = ('hello', 'world')
>>> a
['hello', 'hello', 'world', 1, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Edit: a simple way to solve your problem could be to use the `insert` method of python lists (not slice assigning, I know, but may be closer to what you are wanting to achieve):

```
rl.insert(1, test_sl)
```

Comment: You are awesome!! Every example you posted made it super clear to me. Thank you, swalladge.

Comment: Just a note which may be obvious after reading this answer that the OP can get the desired behaviour with `rl[1:1] = (test_sl,)`

Comment: @MichaelMior good point! I also just edited my answer to include another possible way to solve OP's problem. :)